# Management long running tasks in Aiohttp app

Tags: python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a web application in Aiohttp.

How to manage long running tasks?
I see this scenario. Is this bad or good?

1. User makes request for some long running tasks.
2. Server create task with 
   `new_task = asyncio.create_task()`
   Generate uuid for new task and save it all in dict:

```py
new_task = asyncio.create_task()
uuid_task = uuid.uuid4()
tasks_set.update({
    uuid_task: new_task
})
```

3. Send answer to client with status 202 Accepted and task's uuid.
4. After some time user makes request with task uuid for asking task's status.
5. Server looks for in `tasks_set` for task and get it status:

```py
task = tasks_set.get(uuid_from_client)
if not task:
    raise TaskNotFound # send error, 404 for example
if not task.done():
    # task is not done yet
    answer_to_client('task is not done')
    return
else:
    answer_to_client('task is done. Result: ', task.result())
    tasks_set.pop(uuid_from_client)
```

But I also have to manage timeout for tasks (user has gone and we should stop his task). Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I also have to manage timeout for tasks

You can use [`asyncio.wait_for`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for) to add a timeout to any coroutine. Instead of:

```py
# run coroutine in a new task
new_task = asyncio.create_task(coroutine(...))
```

you can use:

```py
# run coroutine in a new task, for no longer than 10s
new_task = asyncio.create_task(asyncio.wait_for(coroutine(...), 10)
```

`new_task.done()` will be true both if the coroutine completes and if it times out. You can test for timeout by testing `new_task.done() and new_task.exception() is asyncio.TimeoutError`.